# How to know when your tab has been selected on an Office Ribbon

Tags: vsto, ribbonx

I have a plugin (excel 2013 VSTO 4.0 .NET 4.0 ) which has a custom Tab. In this tab I have a drop down control that has a lot of images being loaded. Currently these images are being loaded in the RibbonLoad Event. The downside of course is that my plugin potentially could take a lot of time to load causing the plugin to load slowly causing Excel to disable my plugin.
Is there any event, or any way in which I can delay the loading of the drop down item until someone selects my tab. I am not able to find any event that says someone clicked on my custom tab.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the method that loads the images in to a separate methods and call it in a seperate thread.
[More on Threading in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This may not be best solution but at least better than earlier which blocks your UI thread during image loading.

**OR**

Use [Delay loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/04/19/delay-loading-the-clr-in-office-add-ins.aspx)

By default the addins load behaviour in registries will be 3 which means addins loaded when application starts.
You could go for load behaviour 8,9,16 for loading addins only on demand. Try these different load behaviours and see which one helps you.

Comment: um you cant touch the Excel object model on a non UI thread can you ?

Comment: I have edited my answer with another best solution. I am sure you should be able to access object model in another thread. I have a scenario in Word where I invalidate a control in the ribbon during WindowSelectionChanged without blocking UI thread.